# TabControl.TabPages.Clear() suddenly stopped working

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

`TabControl.TabPages.Clear();` just stopped working. It doesn't clear anything now.

Code:

```
    private void menuItem39_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tabControl.TabPages.Clear();
    }
```

Why would it do this?

Below is the code I use to dynamically add TabPages to the TabControl:

```
public void menuItem7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tabControl.TabPages.Add(new TabPage() { Text = "Untitled" });
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the `menuItem39_Click` is registered OK? try setting some break point at the line `.Clear()` to see if it jumps in there.

Comment: Hi @KingKing, I set a breakpoint and the Click event is being registered and it goes through the process of removing - but it's just that nothing gets removed. I stepped-in the whole way through and checked all the values but nothing looked abnormal (to me) other than when I hovered over TabPages in the code, the thing that popped up said "Tab Count: 0" (when there were still 7 tabs open).

Comment: From the sounds of it you're dynamically creating tab pages and assigning them to your tab control?  Can you edit your question to include that code as well?

Comment: Didn't you forget to refresh your tab control after clearing it's items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are writing very dangerous code, the Clear() method doesn't do what you hope it does.  Start TaskMgr.exe, click the Processes tab.  Use View + Select Columns and tick the USER Objects option.  Locate your program in the list and keep an eye on the displayed value.  Note that calling Clear() does *not* lower the USER Object value.  In all likelihood, you'll see it climb steadily while you use your program.  Very Bad Things happen when the displayed value reaches 10000.

The proper way to remove tab pages is to *dispose* them.  Like this:

```
   while (tabControl1.TabCount > 0) tabControl1.TabPages[0].Dispose();
```

Comment: Thank you again @Hans. I was under the impression that calling Dispose() was no garuntee that the objects would actually get removed from the collection right away (this is what I've read). But now I know so thank you.